# Host CSS classes made available to ShadowDom contents

Tags: css, shadow-dom

As far as I can see even with `mode=open` CSS classes of host are not piercing through Shadow Dom.

Is it possible to make CSS classes defined outside ShadowDom available to its contents?

Answer (score 0):

No, the whole point of shadowDOM is encapsulation.

If you don't want that, then **do not use** shadowDOM.

Web Components can be programmed to accept *some* Global styling with:

- CSS Custom Properties
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties
- ::part
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part